# How to get base URL in Web API controller?

Tags: url, asp.net-web-api, base-url, asp.net-web-api2

I know that I can use `Url.Link()` to get URL of a specific route, but how can I get Web API base URL in Web API controller?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You could use `VirtualPathRoot` property from `HttpRequestContext` (`request.GetRequestContext().VirtualPathRoot`)

Comment: `Request.GetRequestContext().VirtualPathRoot` returns `/`. I self-host Web API on localhost in Windows service using Owin. Any way to get base URL in this case? Thank you.

Comment: Hmm..this should return the correct virtual path. I tried it myself now and it works fine. Could you share how you are setting the virtual path (for example, I do like this: `using (WebApp.Start<Program>("http://localhost:9095/Test"))` where VirtualPathRoot returns `/Test`)

Comment: Ok, this makes sense. I set `http://localhost:5550/` and it correctly returns `/`. What I meant is how to get `http://localhost:5550/` in this case...

Comment: Ok, since you have access to the HttpRequestMessage(`Request.RequestUri`), you could grab the request uri of it and find the scheme,host and port...right?

Comment: new Uri(Request.RequestUri, RequestContext.VirtualPathRoot)

Comment: Request.GetRequestContext().VirtualPathRoot is not working on netcore 1.6.1 as HttpRequestContext doesn't exist there, is there any alternative ?

Answer (score 97):

In the action method of the request to the url  "http://localhost:85458/api/ctrl/"

```
var baseUrl = Request.RequestUri.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority) ;
```

this  will get you  http://localhost:85458

Comment: This is incorrect, it only happens to work if you're running your site as the root site in IIS. If you're running your application within another application, i.e. http://localhost:85458/Subfolder/api/ctrl then this would yield the wrong answer (it wouldn't include "/Subfolder" which it should).

Comment: @Arbiter Getting the base URL for a specific application is different than getting the base of a URL. So it's not that this answer is incorrect, just that there might be a different base url depending on the need

Answer (score 52):

```
Url.Content("~/")
```

worked for me!

Comment: I came here for this anwser :)

Comment: Works on .Net Core 2.2

Answer (score 22):

In .NET Core WebAPI (version 3.0 and above):

```
var requestUrl = $"{Request.Scheme}://{Request.Host.Value}/";
```

Comment: From what dependency is ```Request``` from?

Comment: Request is a property of ApiController (and normal controller). So in code of a controller, no more dependency is needed. @JannickBreunis

Answer (score 16):

This is what I use:

```
Uri baseUri = new Uri(Request.RequestUri.AbsoluteUri.Replace(Request.RequestUri.PathAndQuery, String.Empty));
```

Then when I combine it with another **relative path**, I use the following:

```
string resourceRelative = "~/images/myImage.jpg";
Uri resourceFullPath = new Uri(baseUri, VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute(resourceRelative));
```

Answer (score 10):

I inject this service into my controllers.

```
 public class LinkFactory : ILinkFactory
 {
    private readonly HttpRequestMessage _requestMessage;
    private readonly string _virtualPathRoot;


    public LinkFactory(HttpRequestMessage requestMessage)
    {
        _requestMessage = requestMessage;
        var configuration = _requestMessage.Properties[HttpPropertyKeys.HttpConfigurationKey] as HttpConfiguration;
        _virtualPathRoot = configuration.VirtualPathRoot;
        if (!_virtualPathRoot.EndsWith("/"))
        {
            _virtualPathRoot += "/";
        }
    }

    public Uri ResolveApplicationUri(Uri relativeUri)
    {

        return new Uri(new Uri(new Uri(_requestMessage.RequestUri.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority)), _virtualPathRoot), relativeUri);
    }

}
```

Comment: And how do you inject HttpRequestMessage?

Comment: @RichardSzalay  Autofac has it built in, https://github.com/autofac/Autofac/blob/master/Core/Source/Autofac.Integration.WebApi/RegistrationExtensions.cs#L131  but the general idea is you setup a DI container and then use a message handler to grab the HttpRequestMessage and register it in a per-request handler.

Answer (score 8):

Use the following snippet from the Url helper class

```
Url.Link("DefaultApi", new { controller = "Person", id = person.Id })
```

The full article is available here:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/roncain/archive/2012/07/17/using-the-asp-net-web-api-urlhelper.aspx

This is the official way which does not require any helper or workaround.
If you look at this approach is like ASP.NET MVC

Comment: when using a custom domain on Azure, the Url.Link returns the .websites domain instead of the custom domain, why is that?

Answer (score 5):

```
new Uri(Request.RequestUri, RequestContext.VirtualPathRoot)
```

Answer (score 4):

In ASP.NET Core `ApiController` the `Request` property is only the message. But there is still `Context.Request` where you can get expected info. Personally I use this extension method:

```cs
public static string GetBaseUrl(this HttpRequest request)
{
    // SSL offloading
    var scheme = request.Host.Host.Contains("localhost") ? request.Scheme : "https";
    return $"{scheme}://{request.Host}{request.PathBase}";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is a Web API 2 addition, but `RequestContext` has a `Url` property which is a `UrlHelper`: [HttpRequestContext Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.controllers.httprequestcontext_properties%28v=vs.118%29.aspx). It has `Link` and `Content` methods. Details [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-.us/library/system.web.http.routing.urlhelper%28v=vs.118%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

First you get full URL using 
`HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.ToString();` then replace your method url using Replace("user/login", "").

Full code will be

```
string host = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.ToString().Replace("user/login", "")
```

Answer (score 1):

Base on Athadu's answer, I write an extenesion method, then in the Controller Class you can get root url by `this.RootUrl();`

```
public static class ControllerHelper
{
    public static string RootUrl(this ApiController controller)
    {
        return controller.Url.Content("~/");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

send a `GET` to a page and the content replied will be the answer.Base url : `http://website/api/`

Answer (score 0):

1. Add a reference to System.Web
   `using System.Web;`
2. Get the host or any other component of the url you want
   `string host = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Host;`

Comment: This does not work for .net core 5

Answer (score -1):

From `HttpRequestMessage`

```
request.Headers.Host
```

Answer (score -1):

Al WebApi 2, just calling HttpContext.Current.Request.Path;