# Get Url of current ASP.NET Web Api 2 action

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api2

In ASP.NET Web API 2, how can I get Url of current action. Following is illustrative example.

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("api/someAction")]
public SomeResults GetAll()
{

    var url = /* what to write here*/
    ....

}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

One of the properties of the `ApiController` base class (from which your own controller must be derived) is called `Request`:

```cs
// Summary:
//     Defines properties and methods for API controller.
public abstract class ApiController : IHttpController, IDisposable
{
    // ...

    //
    // Summary:
    //     Gets or sets the HttpRequestMessage of the current System.Web.Http.ApiController.
    //
    // Returns:
    //     The HttpRequestMessage of the current System.Web.Http.ApiController.
    public HttpRequestMessage Request { get; set; }

    // ...
}
```

This gives you access to the `HttpRequestMessage` which has the following method:

```
//
// Summary:
//     Gets or sets the System.Uri used for the HTTP request.
//
// Returns:
//     Returns System.Uri.The System.Uri used for the HTTP request.
public Uri RequestUri { get; set; }
```

Use the `Request.RequestUri` to get the URL of the current action. It will return you a `Uri` object that gives you access to every part of the request's URI.

Finally, you might find the following SO question useful:

- [How to get base URL in Web API controller?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19866192/how-to-get-base-url-in-web-api-controller)

Answer (score 4):

`Request.RequestUri.ToString();`

On MVC this can be:

`Request.Url.ToString();`

See also:

```
Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority);
```

and

```
Request.RequestUri.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority);
```

Both will return, for example:

> http://localhost:60333/

Answer (score 0):

If the question is about Web API, the answer from mLar in this thread worked like charm for me.
Check this out:
[How to get base URL in Web API controller?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19866192/how-to-get-base-url-in-web-api-controller)